# VF compile error: Invalid field in relatedlist referenced in an apex:repeat - but fields exist

Tags: visualforce

I am having an issue where I am creating a  visual force page from a custom object, and calling the details from a child object. Thing is, I can only access two properties of the child object, any other field gives the following error:

```
Error: Invalid field Rate__c for SObject Invoice__c
```

The Name and Account fields appear in my VF page, but any other field throws the error. I've checked the security properties for the fields, and they are visible to all. This seems like it shouldn't be that difficult. I tried using a controller extension, but that it seems like that shouldn't be necessary since I can access the relationship object.

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c" showHeader="false" name="Invoice# {!Invoice__c.Name}" title="Invoice# {!Invoice__c.Name}" cache="false" >
  <body>
    <table>
      <apex:repeat value="{!Invoice__c.Labor_Records__r}" var="Record"> 
        <tr>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!Record.Name}"/></td> <-- This field works
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!Record.Account__c}"/></td> <-- This field works
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!Record.Rate__c}"/></td> <---This field causes error
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!Record.Date_Occured__c}"/></td> <---This field causes error
        </tr>
      </apex:repeat>
    </table>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

*edit*

*I was able to make this error go away by adding the fields 'Rate' and 'Date Occurred' to the master Invoice__c object. The correct data is displayed in the BlockTable, but now I have extra hidden fields on my Invoice__c object. While it works, it still doesn't seem right, so I am still waiting for a better answer.*

Comment: can you post your full visualforce page

Comment: @sf.dev added the rest. It's still a fairly simple page using the default controller

Comment: I don't see any issues in your code.Can you please double check the api name of rate field on Labor Records object

Comment: Can you try replacing apex:repeat with apex:Pageblocktable

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:pageblock title="{!Account.Name}" >
     <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="con">
      <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!con.Title}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!con.Level__c}"/>
     </apex:pageblockTable>
  </apex:pageblock> 
 </apex:page>

Comment: I tried switching it to a pageblock and had the same issue. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: Is it correct that the SObjects, controller and page are all in a managed package with namespace Buzzbold?

Comment: Yes that is correct...I was experimenting with a managed package. I have removed that part from the question since it isn't relevant. I did end up getting this working, but I had to add the fields from the child object'Labor_Record__c' to the master 'Invoice__c' object. This made the error go away and the data displays correctly. Still, that seems like it shouldn't have been necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem

I used a similar custom object with related records using your syntax in my org and reproduced your error:

> Error: Invalid field Qty__c for SObject Quote__c

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" showHeader="false" name="Quote {!Quote__c.Name}" title="Quote__c {!Quote__c.Name}" cache="false" >
     <body>
    <table>
      <apex:repeat value="{!Quote__c.Quote_Items__r}" var="record"> 
        <tr>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!record.name}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!record.Qty__c}"/></td>
        </tr>
      </apex:repeat>
    </table>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

Then I changed the name of the `apex:repeat var=` from `record` to `qi` and it saves successfully

The root of the problem is that `{!record...}` is invoking the standardController's `getRecord()` method which is returning the parent record (Quote__c in my case, Invoice__c in your post). The fields that worked happen to be in the Invoice__c (Name and Account__c) and the other two fields were not present in the parent. Using a `var="somethingOtherthantheKeywordRecord"` will solve this.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" showHeader="false" name="Quote {!Quote__c.Name}" title="Quote__c {!Quote__c.Name}" cache="false" >
  <body>
    <table>
      <apex:repeat value="{!Quote__c.Quote_Items__r}" var="qi"> 
        <tr>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!qi.name}"/></td>
          <td><apex:outputField value="{!qi.Qty__c}"/></td>
        </tr>
      </apex:repeat>
    </table>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```